# Comparing a string with a key and return the value after fuzzy matching of the string

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, compare, string-comparison

I have a dictionary of 200000 companies. I am using the first two words as a key.
For Example :

```
{'Dell international' : ['Dell international services']}
```

1. I am reading a set of text files by lines and checking if the key is present in the line
2. If the key is present in the line , fuzzy matching the value with the line
3. If score is >=90% returning the value and break the loop and move to the next file

Example:

```
if my text file has a line , 'Dell International Services Pvt Ltd'. 
I am matching the previous line with the key , i.e 'Dell international'
Then fuzzy matching the string ('Dell International Services Pvt Ltd') with the value in the dict ('Dell international services') 
if the score is greater than 90% return the value, exiting from the loop and looking in the next file.
```

What I have done so far:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

for file in os.listdir(prs_path}:
    with open(prs_path + file) as fd:
            for line in fd:
                line = str(line.lower()).strip()
                for key, value in dict.items():
                    value = eval(str(value).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))
                    if key in line:
                       score = fuzz.UWratio(line,value)
                       if score >= 90:
                          print(value)
                          continue
```

It is returning the value but I am not able to break the loop after the first match as a result it's comparing the line with other 200000 keys and taking a long time execute.

How do I stop it after the first match and move to the next file?

Comment: Is there any specific reason your using `value = eval(str(value).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))` instead of simply accessing `value[0]`?

Comment: @maxbachman I am removing the braces and apostrophe from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes but why do you convert a list to a string, then remove the braces and then use eval to remove the braces, when all you want to do is to access the first element. At least from the information given I can not see any reason why this would be required. So what are the possible types of value? Is it always a list with one element?

Comment: It's always a list with one element but there are different key value pairs and I am trying to find out the most similar key and returning the value. Your suggestion is valid and I completely forgot about this and went the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the matching into a function and then return from it

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz

def file_match(file_name, comp_dict):
  with open(file_name) as fd:
    for line in fd:
      line = line.lower().strip()
      for key, value in comp_dict.items():
        value = value[0].lower().strip()
        if key in line:
          if fuzz.WRatio(line, value, processor=None, score_cutoff=90):
            return value

for file in os.listdir(prs_path}:
  value = file_match(prs_path + file, comp_dict)
  if value:
    print(value)
```

This applies the following changes:

1. moved the inner loop to a function so it can return from it, since as you noted continue only affects the current loop
2. directly access the first element in your list.
   Using eval for this is slow and simply not what eval is made for.
3. rename dict to comp_dict, since dict is a keyword used by python that should not be hidden.
4. replace the usage of FuzzyWuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz), since it is faster (it only has fuzz.WRatio, but unlinke FuzzyWuzzy RapidFuzz always works with unicode, so it does the same). Directly passing the score_cutoff to WRatio helps to exit early when the score can not be reached. Since you already preprocess the strings beforehand (lowercase + strip) you do not have to do this inside WRatio again, so this can be deactivated.
5. You can use `line.lower().strip()` instead of `str(line.lower()).strip()`, since `line.lower()` will already return a string.